# Android: Sensor delay in SensorEventListener is working differently for different devices(from different manufacturers)

Tags: android, android-studio, sensors, android-sensors, sensormanager

In Oppo mobile phone gyroscope is giving twice the accelerometer data(no of data per time period). In oneplus it is giving 5 times and in MI phone it perfectly giving the same no of data for both accelerometer and gyroscope. Same code block has been used in all mobile phones but I am getting correct result for MI phones where as Oppo and oneplus are giving wrong. Please check and provide some insight.

Code:
sm.registerListener(sensorObject[i].sel, allDeviceSensors.get(i), delay);

// sm is object of sensorManager
// sel is object of SensorEventListener

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71580355/295004) to a similar question.

Comment: I checked your answer but in your question you had same sampling frequency for both accelerometer and gyroscope but in my case the sampling rate is differing for both for different devices though I am assigning the same delay for all.